# Using a deep link to navigate to a fragment in an included navigation graph

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation, android-deep-link

I have a simple scenario in which I have to navigation graphs `navigation_main.xml` and `navigation_nested.xml`, and they look as follows:

**navigation_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/navigation_main"
  app:startDestination="@id/fragment">

  <fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:name="my.package.MyFragment"/>

  <include app:graph="@navigation/navigation_nested"/> 
</navigation>
```

**navigation_nested.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/navigation_nested"
  app:startDestination="@id/another_fragment">

  <fragment
    android:id="@+id/another_fragment"
    android:name="my.package.AnotherFragment">
    <deeplink app:uri="myapp://my/uri/path"/>
  </fragment>
</navigation>
```

Now if I run `findNavController().currentDestination.hasDeepLink(Uri.parse("myapp://my/uri/path"))` it returns `false`, and I can't navigate with the deep link into the destination defined in the nested graph. I know that moving the code from `navigation_nested` into `navigation_main` solves this issue, but I need to keep it in a separate file for reusability purposes.

Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: Why are you calling `hasDeepLink()` on `currentDestination`? If you want to search the whole graph for a deep link, you'd want to call that method on `findNavController().graph`.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Thanks! The reason why I was doing that was because I had no clue on how to access the whole graph

Comment: @ianhanniballake The only part that I don't get then is why `findNavController().handleDeepLink(intent)` returns `false` when ìntent` is an intent with it's data set to the uri defined inside the `<deepLink>`tag

Answer (score 1):

Having hunted the internet far and wide, finding no solution, I'm providing one to this dead question.

Using Kotlin the solution is very tidy;

- create an extension function for the NavController.

```
fun NavController.navigate(directions:NavDirections, @NavigationRes graphId : Int) {
            val currentGraph = graph
            val desiredAction = currentGraph.getAction(directions.actionId)
            val destId = if(desiredAction == null) {
                val graph = navInflater.inflate(graphId)
                currentGraph.addAll(graph)
                graph.getAction(directions.actionId)!!.destinationId
            } else {
                desiredAction.destinationId
            }
            navigate(destId, directions.arguments)
        }
```

- Add the argument(s) to your fragment in the navigation graph (NOT a deeplink) - AS USUAL for a non nested graph situation
  Example:

```
<argument
            android:name="defaultValue"
            android:defaultValue="@null"
            app:argType="java.time.LocalDate"
            app:nullable="true" />
```

- Add a global navigation link (that is what this is after all since we're in the same application)

```
<action
        android:id="@+id/action_global_another_fragment"
        app:destination="@id/another_fragment" />
```

- Navigate to the destination as usual

```
val myArg = LocalDate() // in my example
val directions = AnotherFragmentDirections.actionGlobalAnotherFragment(myArg)
            parent.findNavController().navigate(directions, R.navigation.navigation_nested)
```

**--------------------------------------------------**

**So, the full solution is as follows:**

- Create the extension function for the NavController, or, in java, you could create a static helper class with method perhaps.
- Have a main navigation graph:
  **navigation_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/navigation_main"
  app:startDestination="@id/fragment">

  <fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:name="my.package.MyFragment"/>
<!-- Note; there is no requirement for this include to be present for this example to work -->
  <include app:graph="@navigation/navigation_nested"/> 
</navigation>
```

- Create a nested navigation graph:
  **navigation_nested.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/navigation_nested"
  app:startDestination="@id/another_fragment">

  <fragment
    android:id="@+id/another_fragment"
    android:name="my.package.AnotherFragment">
        <argument
            android:name="defaultValue"
            android:defaultValue="@null"
            app:argType="java.time.LocalDate"
            app:nullable="true" />
  </fragment>
  <action
        android:id="@+id/action_global_another_fragment"
        app:destination="@id/another_fragment" />
</navigation>
```

- Add this code inside e.g. a button click listener in MyFragment

```
val directions = AnotherFragmentDirections.actionGlobalAnotherFragment(LocalDate.now())
            parent.findNavController().navigate(directions, R.navigation.navigation_nested)
```